# Ошибка при архивации всех файлов в папке - OSError: error in opening file.txt for reading

Tags: python

Код для архивации всех файлов в папке:

```
import os
import pyminizip
path = 'C:\\path\\file'
writefiles = []
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(path):
    for line in files:
        writefiles.append(line)
pyminizip.compress_multiple(writefiles, [], 'path.zip', 'password', 5)
```

Но при выполнении ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/1.py", line 8, in <module>
    pyminizip.compress_multiple(writefiles, [], 'path.zip', 'password', 5)
OSError: error in opening file.txt for reading
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
import os
from pyminizip import compress_multiple

os.chdir(path)

src_files = []
dest_paths = []
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk("."):
    for file in files:
        src_files.append(os.path.join(folder, file))
        dest_paths.append(folder)

compress_multiple(src_files, dest_paths, 'd:/download/path.zip', 'password', 5)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/1.py", line 10, in <module>
    pyminizip.compress_multiple(src_files, src_paths, 'path.zip', 'password', 5)
OSError: error in opening 18434.txt for reading

Comment: @krime, см. исправленный ответ...

Comment: Ваш ответ решил мою проблему благодарю, но не могли бы вы обьяснить мне логику os.walk я не очень понимаю

Comment: @krime, проще всего понять логику работы `os.walk()`, "натравив" его на папку с __небольшим__ количеством подпапок и файлов в них, и вывести в цикле на печать `print(folder, subfolder, files)`